# How to get all Property name only in a Class

Tags: c#, class, reflection

How can I get all the property of the following class:

```
public class Employee
{
    int employeeID;
    string lastName;    //  should be (20)  chars only
    string firstName;   //  should be (10)  chars only
    string title;       //  should be (30)  chars only
    string address;     //  should be (60)  chars only
    string city;        //  should be (15)  chars only
    string region;      //  should be (15)  chars only
    string postalCode;  //  should be (10)  chars only
    string country;     //  should be (15)  chars only
    string extension;   //  should be (4)   chars only
    string homePhone;



    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeID;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeID = value;
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName  = value;
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            title = value;
        }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return address;
        }
        set
        {
            address = value;
        }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return city;
        }
        set
        {
            city = value;
        }
    }

    public string Region
    {
        get
        {
            return region;
        }
        set
        {
            region = value;
        }
    }

    public string PostalCode
    {
        get
        {
            return postalCode;
        }
        set
        {
            postalCode = value;
        }
    }

    public string Country
    {
        get
        {
            return country;
        }
        set
        {
            country = value;
        }
    }

    public string Extension
    {
        get
        {
            return extension;
        }
        set
        {
            extension = value;
        }
    }
    public string HomePhone
    {
        get { return homePhone; }
        set { homePhone = value; }
    }

}
```

I tried to use reflection/PropertyInfo but with slight problem, the data type is including in the list:

```
  public PropertyInfo[] getPropertyInfo()
  {
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
        propertyInfos = typeof(Employee).GetProperties();
        return propertyInfos;
   }
```

[image: i need to get the Property name not the datatype]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method returns a `PropertyInfo` data structure for each property, which includes information such as the property name, the property return type, etc. If you just want the name, access the [`Name` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx).

To map an array of `PropertyInfo`s to a collection of the property names, the LINQ `Select` extension method can be used:

```
var propertyNames = getPropertyInfo().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

---

PS: You might consider using [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) to reduce the amount of code in your class:

```
...
public string LastName { get; set; }    //  should be (20)  chars only
public string FirstName { get; set; }   //  should be (10)  chars only
...
```